# sap.ui.getCore().byId() retruning undefined after switching the navigation

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am  calling  `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` in controller `onBeforeRendering: function()`, this is working as expected when I load the page(Tab) for the first time. Now I am switching the page to change one of the value for another function `isPD()` which is returning True OR false, After changing the value, I have validated Console and `isPD()` looks good.Now once I switch back to the page,`sap.ui.getCore().byId()` is returning undefined.( This should return undefines if function `isPD()` condition is met, this is working for the first time but not working once I change the value in `isPD()`.

```js
var oRB2 = new sap.ui.commons.RadioButton("CPCONF_APPROVE", {
  text: '{i18n>acw.common.approveAndAssignTo}',
  tooltip: '{i18n>acw.common.assignReqTo}',
  groupName: '{18n>acw.ui.cp.Confirmation.group1}',
  select: oController.approveSelected
});

vLayout.addContent(oRB2);

if (isPD()) { // check if PD
  approve = getPDDropDown("APPROVE");
  approve.setEnabled(false);
  approve.attachChange(oController.handleChange);
  vLayout.addContent(approve);
}



vLayout.addContent(new sap.ui.core.HTML({
  content: "<span>&nbsp;</span>"
}));
```

```js
onBeforeRendering: function() {


    var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("APPROVE");

    if (isPD()) { // check if PD
      if (app !== undefined)
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("APPROVE").setEnabled(true);
    } else {

      if (app !== undefined)
        app.setVisible(false);
      if (sap.ui.getCore().byId("CPCONF_APPROVE") !== undefined)
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("CPCONF_APPROVE").setText(getI18n("acw.common.approve"));
```

I tried putting `isPD()` before the variable declaration, isPD retunns the correct value but `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` returns undefined. `sap.ui.getCore().byId("APPROVE")` should return "value" and "undefined "depedning on function `isPD()`. which is working on the first load, but after changing the values in `isPD()`, its not working.

Comment: A better way to do this is probably attaching a JSON model to your app for this that all pages can access. Values will reflect the current state no matter what page you're in

Comment: Thanks Jorg for quick response, Can you please elaborate on JSON model, I am trying to update the existing app.

Answer (score 0):

In the component, or in the manifest, create a JSON model (`sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel`) and set it. In the manifest it's simply there, in the component you need to create it manually. Let's say you call it `app`.

In the manifest:

```
"models": {
  "app": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
  }
}
```

In any controller, `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel('app')` should get the model.

`model.getProperty` and `model.setProperty` should get the current value of anything inside the model in any controller. Also, you can bind things to it, like the key of your radiobutton in the settings of `CPCONF_APPROVE`

Comment: I further troubleshooted and seems only for the first time View is getting called from Controller onBeforeRendering: function() , Is there a way to called view each time before the page gets rendered, this is required as when I am switching between the pages value is getting updated in view.